# Remove all table rows from SQLite database table

Tags: android, sqlite, sql-delete

I want to remove all rows that i entered from my SQLite database table. The table name is **tbltask**.
I tried to drop the table and delete * from table, but those are giving me runtime errors.
I want to trigger this event in Button OnClickListner event.

Following code is what I tried:

```
String delete = "DELETE FROM "+DATABASE_TABLE;
db.rawQuery(delete, null);
db.delete(DATABASE_TABLE, null, null);
```

LogCat:

```
11-15 17:45:04.660: DEBUG/AndroidRuntime(300): Shutting down VM
11-15 17:45:04.660: WARN/dalvikvm(300): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x4001d800) 
11-15 17:45:04.710: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(300): FATAL EXCEPTION: main 
11-15 17:45:04.710: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(300): java.lang.NullPointerException 
11-15 17:45:04.710: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(300): at database.com.android.DatabaseAccess.drop(DatabaseAccess.java:258) 
11-15 17:45:04.710: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(300): at com.android.ExtraActivity$3$1.onClick(ExtraActivity.java:61) 
11-15 17:45:04.710: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(300): at com.android.internal.app.AlertController$ButtonHandler.handleMessage(AlertController.java:158) 
11-15 17:45:04.710: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(300): at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99) 
11-15 17:45:04.710: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(300): at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123) 
11-15 17:45:04.710: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(300): at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627) 
11-15 17:45:04.710: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(300): at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
11-15 17:45:04.710: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(300): at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521) 
11-15 17:45:04.710: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(300): at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868) 
11-15 17:45:04.710: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(300): at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626) 
11-15 17:45:04.710: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(300): at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method) 
11-15 17:45:04.781: WARN/ActivityManager(58): Force finishing activity com.android/.ExtraActivity 
11-15 17:45:05.320: WARN/ActivityManager(58): Activity pause timeout for HistoryRecord{45061a70 com.android/.ExtraActivity} 
11-15 17:45:14.857: WARN/ActivityManager(58): Launch timeout has expired, giving up wake lock! 
11-15 17:45:15.402: WARN/ActivityManager(58): Activity idle timeout for HistoryRecord{450141d0 com.android/.WelcomActivity} 
11-15 17:45:20.572: WARN/ActivityManager(58): Activity destroy timeout for HistoryRecord{45061a70 com.android/.ExtraActivity}
```

This is the LogCat output I get for following query:

```
        String delete = "DELETE FROM taskTable";
    db.execSQL(delete);
```

Comment: What errors do you get? Post the logcat output

Comment: what's the error you are getting.... just try this one without the rawquery part. `sqLiteDatabase.delete(MYDATABASE_TABLE, null, null);`

Answer (score 70, accepted):

Just do:

```
db.delete(DATABASE_TABLE, null, null);
```

Note that using rawQuery should work, but can be a potential security risk.

EDIT:

About the problem you have when you use

```
db.execSQL
```

Read the [documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html#execSQL%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Object%5B%5D%29), it says you should not use execSQL with INSERT, DELETE, UPDATE or SELECT

Answer (score 0):

Consensus is to drop and recreate the table, or you can use `DELETE FROM tbltask` which uses a performance operation similar to a TRUNCATE on other dbs.

Answer (score 0):

```
 getWritableDatabase().execSQL("DELETE FROM " + "contacts" + ";");
```

Here contacs is my table name.. Try it..It works for me..

Comment: This explicitly contradicts the documentation: "Execute a single SQL statement that is NOT a SELECT/INSERT/UPDATE/DELETE"

Answer (score 0):

Delete all values from database table use this method in database.

```
private SQLiteDatabase odb;
public void deleteallvalues(){
     odb.delete(TABLE_NAME,null,null)
}
```

this work fine.