# Android delete Record SQLite

Tags: android, sqlite, delete-record

In my activity I have a spinner with data taken from SQLite db by this query:

```
private List<String> ottieniAnni(){
    List<String> result = new LinkedList<String>();

    SQLiteDatabase db = new BHelper(this).getReadableDatabase();

    String sql = "SELECT DISTINCT strftime('%Y',"+GTable.DATE+") FROM "+GTable.TABLE_NAME;
    Cursor c = db.rawQuery(sql, null);

    while (c.moveToNext()){
        result.add(c.getString(0));
    }
    db.close();
    return result;
}
```

Now through button, I want to delete all records in the year chosen by the user. I used the method db.delete (), but so will delete all the records.
Should I set a parameter but do not know how to do it:

```
 SQLiteDatabase db= mHelper.getWritableDatabase();
    db.delete(GiornateTable.TABLE_NAME,   null, null );
    db.close();
```

Comment: You can find the answer over here...

[remove-all-table-rows-from-sqlite-database-table][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8131526/remove-all-table-rows-from-sqlite-database-table

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try like

```
SQLiteDatabase db= mHelper.getWritableDatabase();
int rowcount = db.delete(GiornateTable.TABLE_NAME,
                    "GIVE YOUR COLUMN NAME" + "=?",
                    new String[] { "GIVE YOUR VALUE" });
Log.d("No of record deleted",String.valueOf(rowcount));
```

Answer (score 2):

you can use the same syntax as you do with the select, only for deleting

Comment: Ottengo Il Valore Dalla filatrice (filatrice Nel formato dati aaaa). ma vieni imposto Nel Metodo db.delete? `String annodelete = yearSelector.getSelectedItem () toString (). Db.delete (GiornateTable.TABLE_NAME, GiornateTable.DATA + "? =", annodelete); `